# Show user-friendly error page instead of exception in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, custom-error-pages

Is it possible to make **global error handling** that will **show user-friendly error page instead of showing red exception**?

I already made error handling ([here](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/maintenance/error-reporting)) that will report exception to the backend but what I really would like to achieve is to hide red exception and show something a little bit frendlier.

Comment: Why not display an `alertDialog` which displays a user-friendly message in the production else of the `_reportError` method?

Comment: AlertDialog needs the `context` object. How I'm gonna get `context` object inside `_reportError` method?

Comment: Pass it through as a parameter? I.e. `Future<Null> _reportError(dynamic error, dynamic stackTrace, BuildContext context) async {}`

Comment: `onError: (error, stackTrace) { _reportError(error, stackTrace); });` Is it possible to get it in onError method also since I'm using `runZoned`?

Comment: Are you able to pass it in like `_reportError(error, stackTrace, BuildContext context);`?

Comment: `_reportError` is called in `onError` method. I need it to recieve the `context` in `onError` method first, only then I can pass it to `_reportError` method.

Comment: Mmm maybe this post can provide an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52223152/how-to-show-a-snackbar-from-async-executions-when-no-context-is-available

Comment: I will try that. I really hope it won't show both errors, snackbar and the red exception. Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Official docs:

> When an error occurs during the build phase, the
> [ErrorWidget.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ErrorWidget/builder.html) callback is invoked to build the widget that
> is used instead of the one that failed. By default, in debug mode this
> shows an error message in red, and in release mode this shows a gray
> background.

You can define it in the `builder` method of the MaterialApp widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class CustomError extends StatelessWidget {
  final FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails;

  const CustomError({
    Key key,
    @required this.errorDetails,
  })  : assert(errorDetails != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        child: Text(
          "Something is not right here...",
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      ),
      color: Colors.red,
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
        ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
          return CustomError(errorDetails: errorDetails);
        };

        return widget;
      },
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Welcome,',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
          ),
          FirstName(),
        ],
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstName extends StatelessWidget {
  FirstName({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(null);
  }
}
```

This is how it looks:

[image: Before and after]
(click to enlarge)

Comment: How to test this? What kind of red exception here?

Comment: You can simply throw an exception and instead of the red exception it will show  user friendly message.

Comment: Oo ok I'll try because so far when I throw exception only on console never able to get something on UI which is now I'm digging on this

Comment: Is it necessary to override `builder` in MaterialApp as well?

Comment: Yes if you want to use the ThemeData. If you don't care about ThemeData then use the previous code.

Comment: @Spectarion have you tried the solution on `release` mode. No error text in `release`  mode (empty white screen)

Comment: I make an example updated, check https://dartpad.dev/b4b2bae9438d5a9c238c467f6623cfca?. @AnisAlibegić can you update youy code to latest versions?!

Comment: @FelipeSales Not seeing any code other that default DartPad template? Are you sure you created a gist with that code and shared the correct URL?

Comment: @AnisAlibegić stranger, really opening on anonym window not has content. You can see here: https://gist.github.com/felipecastrosales/b4b2bae9438d5a9c238c467f6623cfca. . I think that this is a bug.

Answer (score 5):

Building on [Anis Alibegić](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7674734/anis-alibegi%c4%87)'s answer:

1. Added Scaffold. Without Scaffold the message appears on top of previously rendered content.
2. Moved more code to the helper method.

Code:

```
void setErrorBuilder() {
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Text("Unexpected error. See console for details.")));
  };
} 

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     setErrorBuilder();

     return MaterialApp(
       builder: (BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
         setErrorBuilder();    
         return widget;
       },
       title: 'Flutter Demo',
       home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why use help-methods in this case?