# flutter ios app shows white screen in testflight mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

flutter  app runs fine in debug mode on simulator but after uploading on app store and running in test flight and after installing to apple device it just shows white screen .**app**
`
name: lapress
description: A new Flutter project.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html

```
version: 1.1.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^4.3.1
  flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1
  connectivity: ^0.4.9
  easy_localization: ^1.4.1
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  sqflite: ^1.3.2+2
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  table_calendar: ^2.2.3
  localstorage: ^3.0.2+5
 


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
  http: ^0.12.2
  intl_translation: ^0.17.10
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.0
  

dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2




flutter:


  uses-material-design: true

 
  assets:
    - image/asset/
    - image/asset/asset_lang/
```

Comment: Share code for your launch screen. Have you added release SHA-1 incase you are using them.

Comment: body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
           
            Image.asset(
              'image/asset/icon.png',
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
            ),

Comment: i am not used any sha1

Comment: can u share your pubspec.yaml file. what's your type of application. eg: e-commerce,todo list etc..

Comment: it is like events marking application on calendar

Comment: Did you check this : https://jatin-95284.medium.com/quick-fix-flutter-ios-app-with-white-screen-after-install-through-testflight-87c63030ddc4

Comment: i did that but same error

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF ✨:

It actually means there is an error which is not displayed in production (it displays red screen in debug mode, but seems you have no error in debug mode), try displaying error even in production (TestFlight) :
[flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors](http://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors) and [stackoverflow.com/a/53640242/305135](http://stackoverflow.com/a/53640242/305135)

Specifically for this, sometimes this helps:

```
Xcode (Good to do)
Product -> Clean

IDE/Command-line (Must do to fix)
Flutter clean
flutter build ios --release

Xcode (Have to do anyways)
Archive
Upload App Store
```

Comment: did all the steps but same error......and it is running on some devices fine but on other it is not.why?

Comment: i have did all these steps but same issue....but the thing is it is working fine on some of the devices but for some of them it is showing just white screen why so?

Comment: It actually means there is an error, try displaying error even in production (TestFlight) : 
https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53640242/305135

Comment: i have tried to show the error screen but no errors were there any other solution